# status de um registro em um determinado intervalo de datas

Tags: tsql, oracle12c

Saudações!
Me deparei com um problema e gostaria de alguma ajuda caso seja possível. Estou desenvolvendo um relatório  financeiro e nesse relatório eu preciso pegar o estado de um título em determinado período. Por exemplo. Digamos que eu tenha um título da venda de um imóvel que foi realizada no mes de fevereiro, e o mesmo tenha sido pago agora em novembro. Preciso que caso eu faça a pesquisa no relatório e coloque uma data anterior ao período de baixa do meu título ele apareça em aberto e se passe de uma data posterior a data da baixa desse título ele venha com o status original. Essa tabela de financeiro não está vinculada  a nenhuma tabela de histórico então meio que eu precisaria buscar isso de forma "manual". Minha ultima tentativa foi criar um CASE verificando que se a data de negociação fosse menor que a data da baixa ele apareceria o valor com a DHBAIXA (data da baixa) vazio, caso contrário me traria o estado atual do título, mas não deu certo. No exemplo a baixo o título teve sua baixa no dia 04-11-2020. Naquele intervalo ali a baixo ele  aparece nulo, porém, se altero a data para o mês 12 ele deveria aparecer baixado já, porém, ainda aparece nulo. Alguém poderia  me ajudar? sou iniciante em BD ainda, então nem conheço todas as funções. Desde já agradeço a atenção

```
SELECT
    FIN.NUFIN ,
    FIN.CODEMP || ' - ' || EMP.NOMEFANTASIA AS EMPRESA ,
    FIN.CODPARC || ' - ' || PAR.NOMEPARC AS PARCEIRO ,
    FIN.DTNEG ,
    FIN.DTVENC ,
    FIN.DHBAIXA ,
    FIN.VLRDESDOB ,
    FIN.VLRBAIXA ,
    FIN.RECDESP ,
CASE 
    WHEN FIN.DTNEG < FIN.DHBAIXA OR FIN.DHBAIXA IS NULL AND FIN.DTNEG BETWEEN  DATE '2020-01-01' AND  DATE '2020-11-01'  THEN NULL ELSE FIN.DHBAIXA END AS DHBAIXA_TESTE      
FROM
TGFFIN FIN
    JOIN TSIEMP EMP ON  FIN.CODEMP = EMP.CODEMP
    JOIN TGFPAR PAR ON FIN.CODPARC = PAR.CODPARC
WHERE
    FIN.NUFIN = 242381
AND FIN.DTNEG BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-11-01'
```

Comment: "determinado período" e se faz uma busca em quase um ano ... para mim ficou pouco claro. O que é dtneg ?

Comment: dtneg seria a data de negociação ou quando o título entrou no sistema. Como foi feito uma troca de sistema estão conferindo se o valor no financeiro bate com o fechamento da contabilidade e então estão pedindo esse relatório.  Então assim, digamos que eu tenha pago esse título em novembro, logo a data da baixa estaria preenchida. E se  nos parâmetros informarem uma data por exemplo de janeiro a outubro, ele tem que aparecer que ainda está em aberto. E caso seja algo parcelado deve aparecer as parcelas pagas apenas referente aos meses dos parâmetros.

Comment: Tentou   WHEN FIN.DHBAIXA IS NULL AND FIN.DTNEG BETWEEN  DATE '2020-01-01' AND  DATE '2020-11-01'  THEN NULL ELSE FIN.DHBAIXA END AS DHBAIXA_TESTE      
FROM

Comment: Sim, sim. Mas o problema é que por exemplo  se eu colocar o período agora em novembro ele está baixado. Mas se eu filtrar de janeiro a outubro ele precisa aparecer em aberto sem o campo DHBAIXA preenchido.

Comment: dica , liste os casos e tente montar o case , talvez vc tenha de fazer uma function

Comment: Tentei montar o case do código mas não deu certo ainda não. Vou ver como montar uma função e tentar montar uma. Sou novo ainda em BD mas está sendo muito bom. Agradeço a dica, amigo. Irei estudar sobre e irei comentar o resultado aqui.

Comment: Mota, muito obrigado por suas dicas. Eu estou conseguindo evoluir utilizando case. Assim que o relatório ficar pronto eu posto aqui. Poderá ajudar mais pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, gente. Consegui resolver o problema. Estou postando aqui a solução caso alguém tenha futuramente a mesma dúvida. Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

```
    SELECT
    FIN.NUFIN ,
    FIN.NUNOTA ,
    --FIN.NUMNOTA ,
/* VERIFICAR SE O NUMERO DA NOTA É DO SISTEMA ANTERIOR OU DO SISTEMA ATUAL*/
    CASE WHEN FIN.NUMNOTA = 0 THEN FIN.AD_NUM_PROTHEUS ELSE TO_CHAR(FIN.NUMNOTA,'999999999999999999999') END AS NUMNOTA_TESTE,
/*FINAL VERIFICAÇÃO */
'Valor Referente a NF - '||/*INICIOPRIMEIROCASE*/CASE WHEN FIN.NUMNOTA = 0 THEN FIN.AD_NUM_PROTHEUS ELSE TO_CHAR(FIN.NUMNOTA,'999999999999999999999') END /*FIMPRIMEIROCASE*/ || ' - '||CASE WHEN 
    (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND  :P_PERIODO.FIN)
    THEN FIN.DHBAIXA END AS HISTORICO,
    FIN.DESDOBRAMENTO ,
    FIN.CODEMP || ' - ' || EMP.NOMEFANTASIA AS EMPRESA ,
    FIN.CODPARC || ' - ' || PAR.NOMEPARC AS PARCEIRO ,
    FIN.DTNEG ,
    FIN.DTENTSAI ,
    FIN.DTVENC ,
    FIN.VLRDESDOB , 
    NAT.DESCRNAT,
CASE WHEN  FIN.RECDESP = 1 THEN 'Receita' Else 'Despesa' END AS RECDESP_CASE  ,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN)THEN FIN.DHBAIXA END AS DHBAIXA_TESTE  ,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN )THEN FIN.VLRBAIXA END AS VLRBAIXA_TESTE,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) THEN FIN.NURENEG END AS NURENEG_TESTE,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (REN.DHALTER BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN )THEN REN.DHALTER END AS DTRENEG_TESTE,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) THEN FIN.NUCOMPENS END AS NUCOMPENS_TESTE,
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (MBC.DHCONCILIACAO BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN )THEN MBC.DHCONCILIACAO END AS DHCONSC_TESTE,
TOP.CODTIPOPER || ' - '|| TOP.DESCROPER  AS MOVIMENTO,
-- INICIO SALDO 
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN ) THEN TRUNC((SELECT 
SUM(VLRDESDOB ) 
FROM TGFFIN FIN
JOIN TGFTOP TOP ON FIN.CODTIPOPER = TOP.CODTIPOPER AND FIN.DHTIPOPER = TOP.DHALTER 
JOIN TGFNAT NAT ON FIN.CODNAT = NAT.CODNAT 
WHERE CODEMP IN :P_EMPRESA
AND  ((:P_RECDESP = 'R' AND FIN.RECDESP = 1 ) OR (:P_RECDESP = 'D' AND FIN.RECDESP = -1 ))  
AND (FIN.CODPARC = :P_PARCEIRO OR :P_PARCEIRO IS NULL )
AND FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN
AND FIN.CODNAT IN :P_NATUREZA 
AND TOP.TIPMOV  NOT IN ('P','O')) - FIN.VLRBAIXA,2) END AS TOTALDESDOB,
-- FIM SALDO
-- INICIO NOVAS ALTERAÇÕES
CASE WHEN (FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN) AND (FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN ) THEN TRUNC((SELECT 
SUM(VLRDESDOB ) 
FROM TGFFIN FIN
JOIN TGFTOP TOP ON FIN.CODTIPOPER = TOP.CODTIPOPER AND FIN.DHTIPOPER = TOP.DHALTER
JOIN TGFNAT NAT ON FIN.CODNAT = NAT.CODNAT 
WHERE CODEMP IN :P_EMPRESA
AND ((:P_RECDESP = 'R' AND FIN.RECDESP = 1 ) OR (:P_RECDESP = 'D' AND FIN.RECDESP = -1 ))
AND (FIN.CODPARC = :P_PARCEIRO OR :P_PARCEIRO IS NULL )
AND FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN
AND FIN.CODNAT IN :P_NATUREZA
AND TOP.TIPMOV  NOT IN ('P','O')
AND FIN.DHBAIXA IS NOT  NULL) - (FIN.VLRDESDOB),2) END AS DIF 
--FIM NOVAS ALTERAÇÕES 
FROM
TGFFIN FIN
    JOIN TSIEMP EMP ON FIN.CODEMP = EMP.CODEMP
    JOIN TGFPAR PAR ON FIN.CODPARC = PAR.CODPARC
    JOIN TGFTOP TOP ON FIN.CODTIPOPER = TOP.CODTIPOPER AND FIN.DHTIPOPER = TOP.DHALTER 
    JOIN TGFNAT NAT ON FIN.CODNAT = NAT.CODNAT 
LEFT JOIN TGFREN REN ON FIN.NUFIN = REN.NUFIN 
LEFT JOIN TGFMBC MBC ON FIN.NUBCO = MBC.NUBCO 
WHERE   
FIN.CODEMP IN :P_EMPRESA 
AND (FIN.CODPARC = :P_PARCEIRO OR :P_PARCEIRO IS NULL )
AND ((:P_RECDESP = 'R' AND FIN.RECDESP = 1 ) OR (:P_RECDESP = 'D' AND FIN.RECDESP = -1 ))
AND (FIN.CODTIPOPER = :P_TOP OR :P_TOP IS NULL )
AND (FIN.VLRDESDOB = :P_VALOR OR :P_VALOR IS NULL )
AND FIN.DTENTSAI BETWEEN :P_PERIODO.INI AND :P_PERIODO.FIN
AND TOP.TIPMOV NOT IN ('P','O')
ORDER BY FIN.CODPARC, FIN.NUMNOTA, FIN.DTENTSAI
´´´
```